# Can I use logical OR || in PHP variable declaractions?

Tags: php, logical-operators

This code works:

```
$foo = getFoo();
if (!$foo) $foo = getBar();
if (!$foo) $foo = getJiggy();
if (!$foo) $foo = getWithIt();
```

I thought I'd seen somewhere a simplification of it with logical operators:

```
$foo = (getFoo() || getBar() || getJiggy() || ...);
```

I figured that the first true statement would get passed, but instead, it's just setting $foo to boolean `true` instead of the return value of `getFoo()`, `getBar()`, etc.

Is there a simplification like what I'm thinking of?

Comment: You're probably thinking of the classic `myfunc() or die()` statement. In any case, no, there's not a way to do what you want. `$foo = getFoo() || $foo = getBar()...` will work, but, ew.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to solve with this yucky thing? :) There needs to be a better way...

Comment: You were probably thinking of JavaScript's coalescing behavior with the `||` operator. What you posted is quite readable, and should be left as-is.

Comment: well, my code's looking for an imageURL, but if the imageURL doesn't exist, it looks in a different (ancient) place for it. My code's probably good enough for that, but I got curious if there was a better way if I had more than one other place to look. In the latter case, I'd probably just use a loop though.

Comment: If you're looking for an image URL - why not just combine all your function calls into one new function that deals with all possible outcomes and use something like `$foo = getRealFoo();`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For JavaScript, `foo = bar || baz;` is a commonly used expression, as the `||` operator has a coalescing behavior.

PHP does not have this behavior with regard to the `||` operator, which returns a boolean value. As such, the more verbose code you originally posted:

```
$foo = getFoo();
if (!$foo) $foo = getBar();
if (!$foo) $foo = getJiggy();
if (!$foo) $foo = getWithIt();
```

is your most readable, and preferable option.

[PHP 5.3 has a shorthand version of the ternary operator, which acts as a coalescing operator:](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)

> Since PHP 5.3, it is possible to leave out the middle part of the ternary operator. Expression expr1 ?: expr3 returns expr1 if expr1 evaluates to TRUE, and expr3 otherwise.

This would allow you to use:

```
$foo = getFoo() ?: getBar() ?: getJiggy() ?: getWithIt();
```

However, that assumes you don't have to worry about compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
$foo = getFoo() or $foo = getBar() or $foo = getJiggy() or $foo = getWithIt();
var_dump($foo);
```

Output

```
string 'Stop Here' (length=9)
```

Function Used

```
function getFoo() {
    return false;
}

function getBar() {
    return false;
}

function getJiggy() {
    return "Stop Here";
}

function getWithIt() {
    return "Hello World";
}
```

Comment: +1 for answering the question. However, I don't advocate this. The original format is more readable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested ternary operator. Something like:

```
$foo = (!$foo)? getFoo() : ((!$foo)? getBar() : getJiggy()) ;
```

Comment: Won't work as expected: this will always assign `getFoo()` when $foo is undefined, else it will assign `getJiggy()`. The assignment is done _after_ this statement is processed: `$foo = ($foo%2 === 0 ? 1 : ($foo%2 === 1 ? 2 : 0));` will _never_ set foo to 0. If $foo was even, its set to one, when odd, it's set to 2, the end.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the weaker-precedence `or` and build up a condition+assignment chain like this:

```
    $foo = getFoo()
OR  $foo = getBar()
OR  $foo = getJiggy()
OR  $foo = getWithIt();
```

For readability and easing others to understand such operator misuse, spacing is essential.

Answer (score 0):

if you *really* want to rewrite your code, you could use [call_user_func](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php), but it's not a very elegant solution:

```
$foo = false;//best declare vars before using them, to avoid warnings in strict mode
$functions = array('getFoo', 'getBar','getJiggy','getWithIt');
while(!$foo && $func = array_shift($functions))
{
    $foo = call_user_func($func,null);//replace null with optional parameters
}
```

But as you can see, this would be even less maintainable...

Comment: Why the down-vote? I merely remarked on the fact that it's an option, _and_ I said it wasn't a good one. It works, though, whereas some of the other answers here don't

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
($foo = getFoo()) || ($foo = getBar()) || ($foo = getJiggy());
```

Comment: @Baba, it's compact, and easy to think the original author mistakenly missed the second `=` in `$foo == getFoo()`. It makes it more volatile and less expressive of intent.

Comment: @zzzzBov the OP asked for a "simplification" of his notation. He didn't say a word about readability or best practice.